# can any one help me how to reverse every alternate element and append it to end of list

Tags: java

can any one help me how to reverse every alternate element and append it to end of list

for example

I/P: a-1-b-2-c-3(Linked list)
O/P should be: a-b-c-1-3-2

Logic should reverse every alternate element and append it to end of list.

Comment: what you have tried out ??

Comment: wth is alternate element?

Comment: Your reverse doesn't make sense. Only 2 and 3 are reversed

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class LinkedListExample {
     public static void main(String args[]) {

         /* Linked List Declaration */
         LinkedList<String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();

         /*add(String Element) is used for adding the elements to the linked list*/
         linkedlist.add("a");
         linkedlist.add("1");
         linkedlist.add("b");
         linkedlist.add("2");
         linkedlist.add("c");
         linkedlist.add("3");

         /*Display Linked List Content*/
         System.out.println("Linked List Content: " +linkedlist);
         for(int i=1;i<linkedlist.size();i++)
         {
             linkedlist.addLast(linkedlist.get(i)); //Adding the node at last
             linkedlist.remove(i);     //Removing Node from the previous positions    
         }
         System.out.println("Final Content: " +linkedlist); 
     }
}
```